# When does one get the error message "jobs : not found"?

Tags: man, jobs

When does the `jobs` command issue the message `jobs : not found`?
Also, why does the command `man jobs` refuse to show any entry for the command `jobs`?
P.S. : I am able to successfully execute the `jobs` command on the terminal

Comment: Shell builtins usually don't have dedicated man pages. Their man pages can be found using `man builtins` instead.

Comment: Is that the exact error message? How are you running that `jobs` command?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : I found this question in a book. I did not get any error message on running the command

Comment: The string "not found" does not appear anywhere in the file jobs.c from the Bourne Shell source code. So you either use a Bourne Shell from before 1989 or this was another shell.

Comment: @crisron Are you talking about this book: [UNIX Concepts and Applications - Fourth Edition](http://mhhe.com/das/uca)?

Comment: `man builtins` or [`help <the_buitin_command>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22992052/4970442)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jobs` is not a real command, but a command that is builtin to the shell that you're using:

```
martin@dogmeat:~$ type jobs
jobs is a shell builtin
```

When you try to run it without a shell, you'll get an error message, because there is no binary executable called `jobs`.

It also doesn't have a manpage because it's just a builtin. Look in `man builtins` as Marco said, in `man bash` or in the manpage of the respective shell that you're using if you're not using `bash`.

---

EDIT: to explain what running a program without a shell means: when a process in Linux wants to launch another process ([fork and exec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec)), it can either wrap this process in a shell or launch it directly without a shell. For example, in `perl` you can use the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function to launch a new process. This works fine with a real program files like `echo` (I've loaded the `warnings` module here too so we can see error messages):

```
martin@martin ~ % ll /bin/echo 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31K Jan 17  2013 /bin/echo*
martin@martin ~ % perl -Mwarnings -e 'system "echo", "test"'
test
```

But this does not work with a shell builtin like `jobs`, because there is no binary file `jobs`:

```
martin@martin ~ % perl -Mwarnings -e 'system "jobs"'
Can't exec "jobs": No such file or directory at -e line 1.
```

Of course when you're already working inside an interactive shell, you probably won't stumble over this issue. But this is relevant in some other situations, for example when you're using the Gnome <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run dialog. It doesn't wrap your command in a shell, and therefore real binaries, work fine, while trying to run `jobs` will just show an error message.

From your original error message `jobs : not found` I had assumed that you're somehow not in a shell, because inside a shell `jobs` should of course work fine.

Comment: Or `help jobs` if you're on Bash.

Comment: I didn't even know about `help`, but then again, I'm using `zsh` and that doesn't support it :/

Comment: @MartinvonWittich : What do you mean when you say `When you try to run it without a shell` ?

Comment: You can also use the command: `type -a jobs`. With the Bash shell you can access individual commands help using the `help` command: `help jobs`.

Comment: @crisron I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich : Thanx a ton. I got your explanation!!

Answer (score 3):

I can get that error message with:

```
$ ash -c $'Steve\rjobs\\ '
jobs : not found
```

`ash` actually outputs:

```
ash: 1: Steve\rjobs : not found
```

But on a terminal, that `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, and the `jobs: not found` overwrites the `ash: 1: Steve`.

Other than that, your error message may suggest that whatever tried to execute the `jobs` command could not find it.

There's a `jobs` builtin command in all shells of the `csh` (where it originated), POSIX and `fish` families. It lists the *jobs* currently maintained by an interactive shell, so it has no meaning outside a shell and is implemented as a builtin command of the shell (see a given shell documentation for the corresponding `jobs` documentation, or [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html)).

There is often no `jobs` command as an executable file (though POSIX does require that there be), and where there is like on Solaris, it does nothing (as `jobs` is a `ksh` script there that calls the ksh `jobs` builtin, it just reports the jobs (so none) of that new `ksh` shell that interprets the script).

On those systems that have no `jobs` command in the file system, commands that try to execute `jobs` without invoking a shell to parse a command line would report an error:

```
$ perl -le 'exec "jobs" or die "jobs: $!"'
jobs: No such file or directory at -e line 1.
$ env jobs
env: jobs: No such file or directory
$ find . -prune -exec jobs \;
find: `jobs': No such file or directory
$ rc -c jobs
jobs not found
```

Those that do call a shell would succeed, but because they would start a *new* shell, that shell would have no job to report:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {system("jobs")}'
$ expect -c 'system jobs'
$ perl -le 'exec "jobs || :" or die "jobs: $!"'
$ python -c 'import os; os.system("jobs")'
$
```

Answer (score 1):

How old is that book? Unix shells haven't always had job control. The original Bourne shell didn't, and for a while it was common for the 2 choices to be `sh` (Bourne, no job control) and `csh` (job control). The book's answer might be that `jobs` will be `not found` when you're using Bourne shell.

The only shell I can easily find now without a `jobs` command is `posh`.

In `zsh` you can run `disable jobs` first, and then `jobs` will be `not found`.

Comment: OP is most likely referring to this book: [UNIX Concepts and Applications - Fourth Edition](http://mhhe.com/das/uca)? The question reads: "The jobs command issued the message `jobs: not found`. When does that normally happen?"